# python process JS and loop though to get data

Tags: python, regex, loops, web-scraping, beautifulsoup

I have some intricate JS data I scrape and I need some help looping through and extracting data here is the JS:

```
score = 0;
    var AnswerRight = false;

        AnswerRight = false;

                if ($('input[name=Guess1]').val() != "") {
                    if (trim($('input[name=Guess1]').val().toUpperCase()) == '7Y-6') {

                        AnswerRight = true;
                    }
                }

                if ($('input[name=Guess1]').val() != "") {
                    if (trim($('input[name=Guess1]').val().toUpperCase()) == '-6+7Y') {

                        AnswerRight = true;
                    }
                }

                if ($('input[name=Guess1]').val() != "") {
                    if (trim($('input[name=Guess1]').val().toUpperCase()) == 'F(Y)=7Y-6') {

                        AnswerRight = true;
                    }
                }

        if ($('input[name=Guess1]').val() != "") {
            if (AnswerRight) {
                $('#tick1').show();
                $('#cross1').hide();
                score = score + 1;
            } else {
                $('#tick1').hide();
                $('#cross1').show();
            }
        }

        AnswerRight = false;

                if ($('input[name=Guess2]').val() != "") {
                    if (trim($('input[name=Guess2]').val().toUpperCase()) == '-27') {

                        AnswerRight = true;
                    }
                }

        if ($('input[name=Guess2]').val() != "") {
            if (AnswerRight) {
                $('#tick2').show();
                $('#cross2').hide();
                score = score + 1;
            } else {
                $('#tick2').hide();
                $('#cross2').show();
            }
        }

        AnswerRight = false;

                if ($('input[name=Guess3]').val() != "") {
                    if (trim($('input[name=Guess3]').val().toUpperCase()) == '-18') {

                        AnswerRight = true;
                    }
                }

        if ($('input[name=Guess3]').val() != "") {
            if (AnswerRight) {
                $('#tick3').show();
                $('#cross3').hide();
                score = score + 1;
            } else {
                $('#tick3').hide();
                $('#cross3').show();
            }
        }

        AnswerRight = false;

                if ($('input[name=Guess4]').val() != "") {
                    if (trim($('input[name=Guess4]').val().toUpperCase()) == '4') {

                        AnswerRight = true;
                    }
                }

        if ($('input[name=Guess4]').val() != "") {
            if (AnswerRight) {
                $('#tick4').show();
                $('#cross4').hide();
                score = score + 1;
            } else {
                $('#tick4').hide();
                $('#cross4').show();
            }
        }

        AnswerRight = false;

                if ($('input[name=Guess5]').val() != "") {
                    if (trim($('input[name=Guess5]').val().toUpperCase()) == '7') {

                        AnswerRight = true;
                    }
                }

        if ($('input[name=Guess5]').val() != "") {
            if (AnswerRight) {
                $('#tick5').show();
                $('#cross5').hide();
                score = score + 1;
            } else {
                $('#tick5').hide();
                $('#cross5').show();
            }
        }

        AnswerRight = false;

                if ($('input[name=Guess6]').val() != "") {
                    if (trim($('input[name=Guess6]').val().toUpperCase()) == '4') {

                        AnswerRight = true;
                    }
                }

        if ($('input[name=Guess6]').val() != "") {
            if (AnswerRight) {
                $('#tick6').show();
                $('#cross6').hide();
                score = score + 1;
            } else {
                $('#tick6').hide();
                $('#cross6').show();
            }
        }

        AnswerRight = false;

                if ($('input[name=Guess7]').val() != "") {
                    if (trim($('input[name=Guess7]').val().toUpperCase()) == '9X+96') {

                        AnswerRight = true;
                    }
                }

                if ($('input[name=Guess7]').val() != "") {
                    if (trim($('input[name=Guess7]').val().toUpperCase()) == '3(3X+32)') {

                        AnswerRight = true;
                    }
                }

        if ($('input[name=Guess7]').val() != "") {
            if (AnswerRight) {
                $('#tick7').show();
                $('#cross7').hide();
                score = score + 1;
            } else {
                $('#tick7').hide();
                $('#cross7').show();
            }
        }

        AnswerRight = false;

                if ($('input[name=Guess8]').val() != "") {
                    if (trim($('input[name=Guess8]').val().toUpperCase()) == '9X²-2X+7') {

                        AnswerRight = true;
                    }
                }

        if ($('input[name=Guess8]').val() != "") {
            if (AnswerRight) {
                $('#tick8').show();
                $('#cross8').hide();
                score = score + 1;
            } else {
                $('#tick8').hide();
                $('#cross8').show();
            }
        }

        AnswerRight = false;

                if ($('input[name=Guess9]').val() != "") {
                    if (trim($('input[name=Guess9]').val().toUpperCase()) == '4(X²-10X+32)') {

                        AnswerRight = true;
                    }
                }

                if ($('input[name=Guess9]').val() != "") {
                    if (trim($('input[name=Guess9]').val().toUpperCase()) == '4X²-40X+128') {

                        AnswerRight = true;
                    }
                }

        if ($('input[name=Guess9]').val() != "") {
            if (AnswerRight) {
                $('#tick9').show();
                $('#cross9').hide();
                score = score + 1;
            } else {
                $('#tick9').hide();
                $('#cross9').show();
            }
        }

        AnswerRight = false;

                if ($('input[name=Guess10]').val() != "") {
                    if (trim($('input[name=Guess10]').val().toUpperCase()) == '12') {

                        AnswerRight = true;
                    }
                }

        if ($('input[name=Guess10]').val() != "") {
            if (AnswerRight) {
                $('#tick10').show();
                $('#cross10').hide();
                score = score + 1;
            } else {
                $('#tick10').hide();
                $('#cross10').show();
            }
        }

        AnswerRight = false;

                if ($('input[name=Guess11]').val() != "") {
                    if (trim($('input[name=Guess11]').val().toUpperCase()) == '6') {

                        AnswerRight = true;
                    }
                }

        if ($('input[name=Guess11]').val() != "") {
            if (AnswerRight) {
                $('#tick11').show();
                $('#cross11').hide();
                score = score + 1;
            } else {
                $('#tick11').hide();
                $('#cross11').show();
            }
        }

        AnswerRight = false;

                if ($('input[name=Guess12]').val() != "") {
                    if (trim($('input[name=Guess12]').val().toUpperCase()) == '-1') {

                        AnswerRight = true;
                    }
                }

        if ($('input[name=Guess12]').val() != "") {
            if (AnswerRight) {
                $('#tick12').show();
                $('#cross12').hide();
                score = score + 1;
            } else {
                $('#tick12').hide();
                $('#cross12').show();
            }
        }

    if (score < 12) {
        $('#Checkbutton').text('Check again').css({'width':'150px'});
    }
    if (score >= 9) {
        $('#Trophybutton').show();
        $('#Trophybutton').val('Claim Your Trophy for ' + score + ' out of 12');
    }
    if(score==12) {
        $('#Checkbutton').hide();
    }
}
```

I will give an example of what I want to scrape so you can see each question is named Guess then a number so you can see:

```
if ($('input[name=Guess1]').val() != "") {
                    if (trim($('input[name=Guess1]').val().toUpperCase()) == '7Y-6') {

                        AnswerRight = true;
                    }
                }
```

so I would like to get the value 7y-6

but you can see in the code above there's more answers for guess 1 like -6+7y since it can be solved in multiple ways however I just want the first answer to every question:

so the next question answer I would like to get is within:

```
if ($('input[name=Guess2]').val() != "") {
                    if (trim($('input[name=Guess2]').val().toUpperCase()) == '-27') {

                        AnswerRight = true;
                    }
                }
```

and the value I would like to extract is -27

I would like to do this for every question there so loop through for each one and then display then just print out the answers.

How would I do this? Im thinking regex - I have tried but it doesn't work for me hahaha.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could use this re: `Guess\d{1,3}.*?==\s\'(.*?)\'`

### Code

```py
import re

answers = re.findall(r"Guess\d{1,3}.*?==\s\'(.*?)\'", js_text_code)
```

Assuming you have the code in `js_text_code`.

`answers` will be a list like this:

```py
['7Y-6', '-6+7Y', ... ]
```

### Pattern explanation

- `Guess`: Literal text 'Guess'
- `\d{1,3}`: One, two, or three digits (assuming this number could be at least of three digits)
- `.*?==`: Any characters until the first `==`
- `\s`: A space.
- `\'`: The open simple quote.
- `(.*?)\'`: Any characters until the first closed simple quote. And making a group of this characters (this is the part you want).